# Average and Annual rainfall in R?

Tags: r, precipitation

I have rainfall data for more than 50 years in a column. I need to get total rainfall and average rainfall for each year.

How can I do it in R?

Comment: There does not appear to be a GIS component to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command to calculate a mean in R is:

> mean(yourdataframe$yourcolumn)

Without knowing more about the format of your data, I'm not sure what else to add.

Comment: The data is continuous in same column for all years so I cannot directly take the mean. It has rainfall data for year 1 from row 1 to row 365 and year 2 from row 366 to row 730 in same column and so on. I need to specify the number of row to calculate the mean for each year.

Comment: OK, let's say you have 10 years worth of data, and the first year is 2000.

Comment: Since you need your mean aggregated by year, take a look at "tapply". If you do not have a column for date, you will have to create one that takes into account leap years. You could likely use "rep" to create the year column eg., years <- c(rep(2000,365),rep(2001,365),rep(2002,365)) ...

Comment: Hi. Have you checked the dplyr package? It's has a really cool grammar using pipes (`%>%`). Try `group_by(data, year) %>% summarize(result = mean(rain))`. Maybe you'll have to `na.rm=TRUE`, too.